# Reset counter in new \chapter before the first \section

Tags: math-mode, counters

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\chapter{First chap}
\section{First sec}
\begin{lemma}
this one is correct.
\end{lemma}

\chapter{Second chap}
\begin{lemma}
This number is wrong.
\end{lemma}

\section{Second sec}
\begin{lemma}
this one is correct again.
\end{lemma}
```

Obviously I would like to have the lemma in the 2nd chapter before the Second sec to start at zero. But how?

Comment: The number is “2.0.1”; what do you expect it to be?

Comment: @egreg only in 2015 release

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hidden feature!

Comment: @egreg In my actual work there are some lemmas and theorems before the new chapter, so the first lemme in the new chapter has number i.e. 4.0.3 ; and this does not look fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX < 2015: The number of the `lemma` is only reset, when `section` is increased, not `chapter`. `\@addtoreset` helps to reset `lemma`, if `chapter` is increased:

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{lemma}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

In the recent LaTeX release 2015/01/01, this is no longer necessary, because the counter reset is implemented in a transitive way.

### Number format

If the section number `0` should be suppressed, then the following redefinition of `\thelemma` helps:

```
\renewcommand*{\thelemma}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 %
    \thechapter
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{lemma}%
}
```